# Can I paste multiple filters to a pivot table?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, pivot-table

Is there a way in Excel to paste in multiple items as pivot table filters? If I have a list of 15 codes out of a larger set of possible values, it's tedious and error-prone to scroll around to find the ones I'm interested in.

There is an add-in that works on SSAS sources that lets you paste in a list of entries but it doesn't work on local pivot sources.

Comment: No, it's a generalized problem that I am simplifying here. It's never the same subset from day to day.

Comment: 2010 in this case.